# Run an msi silently with arguments

Tags: command-line, wix, windows-installer, silent-installer

I have created an msi which has 4 dialogs.
All 4 dialogs have single button like this:-
1st dialog :- Next Button (Text on Button :- Next)
2nd dialog :- Next Button (Text on Button :- Next)
3rd dialog :- Install Button (Text on Button :- Install)
4th dialog :- Finish Button (Text on Button :- Finish)

I want to run this msi silently through Command Prompt.
I checked solutions on net which tells this command:-
MyMsi.msi /quiet /qn /norestart

But i want to know, how can i specify next button click through CommandPrompt so that silent install goes on.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify button clicks from the command line. However you can specify properties:

- If there are any text edit boxes, check boxes or radio buttons, they will be associated with a property, and you can specify the property's value using a command line argument of the format `PROPERTYNAME=DesiredValue`.
- If you can select features in your wizard, there are special properties, including [ADDLOCAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367536), that you can specify to tell Windows Installer to select (or unselect) a list of features.
- Directories can also be specified, if they're public (no lower case letters in their property names.) So if you can change the installation location, this is typically tied to a property named either TARGETDIR or INSTALLDIR, but it could be a different property depending on how you authored your package.
- If, for example, there are custom actions that fire during the InstallUISequence, but not elsewhere, and are required for your package to install correctly, you should fix the authoring of your package to not require this. Otherwise it will not support silent installation.

Finally, if all your wizard pages are merely informative, then using merely `/qn` or `/qb` ([aka `/quiet` or `/passive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024)) will be enough. This is often enough for a default installation.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this like this:-

MyMSI.msi /QN

it will run the MSI in a silent mode and it will consider all the button clicks itself and go ahead and complete the installation.